# How to obtain the minimal index n in a list (A) so that Total[A[[1;;n]]] is bigger than a specific value m?

Tags: list-manipulation

Imagine the A array is `{1,2,3,4,5,1,2}` and `m = 4`. Then in this case, `Total[A[[1;;3]]]` is 6, so 3 is the minimal index that the summation of the first n elements are bigger than 4. I try to do it using For loop but it's not efficient.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem where function `LengthWhile` is very useful:

```
findIndex[list_List, m_?NumericQ] := Module[{sum = 0},
  LengthWhile[list, (sum += #) <= m &] + 1
];
findIndex[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2}, 4]
```

> 3

If you're instead interested in the elements of the list, use `TakeWhile` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
m = 4;
LengthWhile[Accumulate@A, # < m &] + 1
```

> 3

Answer (score 1):

```
A = Range[5]~Join~{1, 2};
m = 4;

sums = FoldList[Plus, A]
method1 = Position[sums < m // Thread, False][[1, 1]]
method2 = Total@Boole[sums < m // Thread] + 1;
method3 = Total@UnitStep[m - sums] + 1;
method1 == method2 == method3
```

> {1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 16, 18}
>
> 3
>
> True

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2};
```

"Using `SequenceCases`"

```
Length @ First @ SequenceCases[list, _?(Total[#] <= 4 &)] + 1
```

3

```
Length @ First @ SequenceCases[list, _?(Total[#] <= 10 &)] + 1
```

5

Answer (score 1):

Using `FirstCase` and `Position`:

```
First @@ Position[#, FirstCase[#, x_ /; x > 4]] &@Accumulate[l]

(*3*)

First @@ Position[#, FirstCase[#, x_ /; x > 10]] &@Accumulate[l]

(*5*)
```